# Two where "date" clause to have different column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to have 2 different columns with different date in mysql

For example I have this table

```
id     name     amount     date

1      Jane     20.00      2015-08-14
2      Joe      10.00      2015-08-15
3      Joe      20.00      2015-08-21
4      Jane     30.00      2015-09-21
5      Joe      20.00      2015-09-25
6      Jane     10.00      2015-09-25
```

I want to get the sum of amount `groupby` name and display two columns for different date one is 
`where date <= '2015-08-31'` and the other one  is
`where date <= '2015-09-30'`

My desired output is

```
id    name    amount_aug    amount_sep
1     Jane    20.00         60.00
2     Joe     30.00         50.00
```

My query so far is `select name, SUM(amount) amount_sum from table_name groupby name` which will simply output

```
name     amount_sum
Jane     60.00
Joe      50.00
```

Comment: You can sum the amount with case when the date group by the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  name,
  SUM(
    IF( date <= '2015-08-31', amount, 0 )
  ) amount_aug,
  SUM(
    IF( date <= '2015-09-30', amount, 0 )
  ) amount_sep
FROM table_name
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Can use also IF(`BETWEEN "2015-08-01" AND "2015-09-31"`, ...)

Comment: @Balakrishnan The OP specifically wants the sum of `aug`+`sep` in `amount_sep`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
select
    name,
    sum(case when date <= '2015-08-31' then amount else 0 end) amount_on_or_before_aug,
    sum(case when date <= '2015-09-30' then amount else 0 end) amount_on_or_before_sept
from table_name
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, sum(b.amount) AS 'amount_aug', sum(a.amount) AS 'amount_sep'
FROM table_name a
LEFT JOIN table_name b ON a.id = b.id AND b.date <= '2015-08-31'
WHERE a.date <= '2015-09-30'
GROUP BY a.name
```